# JavaFX JDBC некооректно отображаються русские символы

Tags: javafx, jdbc

Получаю данные из textField и отправляю в базу, но в базе все русские символы отображаються как '?', кодировка в базе utf8_bin.
Так отображаются символы только из textfield, если из CMS ее наполнять то все нормально...

Comment: А в строке на подключение к базе кодировка задана явно?

Comment: @Maxim, вы имеете ввиду characterEncoder? Если да то как его установить через класс MysqlDataSource

Comment: @Maxim, нашел как. Такой вопрос, а можно как-то сделать что бы подклчюения к бд были по определённой кодировки сейчас у меня стоит latin1, как изменить на utf8

Comment: Я имел в виду вот эту строку `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/administer?characterEncoding=utf8`, а не `DataSource`
И проверьте кодировку всего чего можно в mysql, не только базы, но и таблиц.

Comment: У себя использую в jdbc ссылке `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`.

Comment: @Maxim да да именно это я и сделал что бы все корректно было, но считаю что это костыли так как это явное указание, а по умолчанию стоит latin1...
Так вот вопрос, что нужно сделать что бы подключение к базе данных было всегда по выбраной мной кодировке?

Comment: Я вчера пробежался по системным переменным, у меня где-то остался шведский по умолчанию (где-то в 5 переменных), и что сможет поломать каждый пункт я подсказать не смогу. Может быть у вас тоже где-то в процессе хождения данных идет перекодирование на шведский.